# can't get the last saved value (file/image) in an edit magento form

Tags: forms, magento, field

I'm workin on a Magento backed Module, in my image form I have this field to add image :

```
$fieldset->addField('imgsrc', 'image',
          array('label' => 'Upload Image',
                'class' => 'required-entry',                      
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'imgsrc',
              ));
```

Whene I add a new image, everything is workin well. But whene I try to edit one of my saved images, there's no value on this field (empty) ! 
How can I fix it ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually saving the image? For example in the saveAction of your controller you would need to have something like:

```
if (isset($_FILES['brand_logo']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['brand_logo']['tmp_name']))) {

            try {
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('brand_logo');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png')); // or pdf or anything
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'brands' . DS;
                $uploader->save($path, $img_token . '_photo_' . $_FILES['brand_logo']['name']);

                $data['brand_logo'] = 'brands/' . $img_token . '_photo_' . $uploader->getCorrectFileName($_FILES['brand_logo']['name']) . '';
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }
        } else {
            if (isset($data['brand_logo']['delete']) && $data['brand_logo']['delete'] == 1) {
                $data['brand_logo'] = '';
            } else {
                unset($data['brand_logo']);
            }
        }
```

You would need to change 'brand_logo' to 'imgsrc' and 'brands' to folder location that you want the uploaded images saved too.

Comment: Yes ! everything is ok with the saveAction, and i can access to my saved data from the front template!
My probleme is whene i try de Edit this form